# qmake subdirs template run all app in the same time

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake, subdirectory

I'm having root project:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG += ordered
SUBDIRS += \
    AppTest \
    TestStub
```

Both `AppTest` & `TestStub` are `app TEMPLATE`. and make socket communication between each. The problem is the root project only can execute only one subproject.(execute one, another auto-closed)

Is possible execute both sequentially in build order?

Comment: The project itself can execute nothing at all. Are you talking about QtCreator? You may need to write a custom run script.

Comment: @StanleyF. Yes, Using QtCreator to make a socket test for both server & client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the settings in Tools > Options > Build&Run > General. There is an option "Stop applications before building". Select "None".

[image: QtCreator Settings]

This will prevent that QtCreator closes a running application when starting another application from the same project.

Then you can start / debug one app, select the other app in the debug / run selector, and start the second. Both should be running then

[image: QtCreator Debug Project]

Comment: If this option could define in qmake pro file will be better. Because of 'none' isn't the default option of QtCreator.

Comment: qmake is independent of QtCreator, just Qt specific make tool. QtCreator is the IDE, and this is a behaviour of that IDE. Visual Studio would behave differently, or Eclipse, or whatever IDE you use. But it is a global setting in QtCreator, so you only have to change it once

Answer (score 2):

QtCreator does not allow to specify multiple executables. You need to write a custom run script that starts both applications.

In the project's *Run Settings* you can set the script as custom executable. Just press *Add*, select *Custom Executable*, and insert the path to your script in the field below.

[image]

Comment: This is handy if you need to run both application as close in time to each other as possible